# Calling method of another router-view's component / Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have two `<router-view/>`s: main and sidebar. Each of them is supplied with a component (*EditorMain.vue* and *EditorSidebar.vue*).

*EditorMain* has a method `exportData()`. I want to call this method from *EditorSidebar* on button click.

**What is a good way of tackling it?**

- I do use vuex, but i don't wanna keep this data reactive since the method requires too much computational power.
- I could use global events bus, but it doesn't feel right to use it together with vuex (right?)
- I could handle it in root of my app by adding event listener to router-view `<router-view @exportClick="handleExportData">` and then target editor component, but it does not feel right as well as later i could need 100 listeners.

Is there any good practice for this? Or did i make some mistakes with the way app is set up? Did is overlooked something in documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two more years of my adventure with Vue I feel confident enough to answer my own question. It boils down to communication between router views. I've presented two possible solutions, I'll address them separately:

## Events bus

> Use global events bus (but it doesn't feel right to use it together with vuex)

Well, it may not feel right and it is surely not a first thing you have to think about, but it is perfectly fine use-case for event-bus. The advantage of this solution would be that the components are coupled only by the event name.

## Router-view event listeners

> I could handle it in root of my app by adding event listener to router-view <router-view @exportClick="handleExportData"> and then target editor component, but it does not feel right as well as later i could need 100 listeners.

This way of solving this problem is also fine, buy it couples components together. Coupling happens in the component containing `<router-view/>` where all the listeners are set.

Big number of listeners could be addressed by passing an object with *event: handler* mapping pairs to `v-on` directive; like so:

```
<router-view v-on="listeners"/>

...

data () {
   return {
      listeners: {
         'event-one': () => console.log('Event one fired!'),
         'event-two': () => console.log('The second event works as well!')
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could [create a plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html) for handling exports:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

ExportPlugin.install = function (Vue, options) {
  const _data = new Map()
  Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$exporter', {
      value: {
          setData: (svg) => {
              _data.set('svg', svg)
          },
          exportData: () => {
              const svg = _data.get('svg')
              // do data export...
          }
       }
  })
}

Vue.use(ExportPlugin)
```

Using like:

```
// EditorMain component
methods: {
    setData (data) {
        this.$exporter.setData(data)
    }
}

// EditorSidebar
<button @click="$exporter.exportData">Export</button>
```

Comment: sounds like an interesting approach, however i'm not sure how could i get private data from _EditorMain_ inside of plugin's `value: () => {}` function.

Comment: Right. And how do i trigger writing the data then?

Comment: Is the data coming from an API? If so you could do something like `this.$store.commit('export/data')` in the success callback.

Comment: no, it is not coming from API. It is processed SVG. Processing of this SVG costs a lot of computational power and it contens change quite often - sometimes every tick. That's why it can't be saved in a state.

Comment: I had another thought, see if my updated answer looks like a better approach.

Comment: That's right, however except for not-importing it in every component, i don't see any difference between this and events bus. I wasn't aware of plugins. Definitely good to check out. Thanks for your effort, i will wait for some other voices, maybe somebody else has some insightful thoughts :)